# Appium - Pick Two days after a specific day of month

Tags: java, appium, gauge

I am trying to pick two days after the current day of month. In my StepImplementation class, i wrote a function like this but it gives me an error:

```
@Step("pick two days after current day")
    public void getCurrentDayOfMonth(String day) throws InterruptedException {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        int dayToPick = dayOfMonth + 2;
        day = String.valueOf(dayToPick);

        appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='" + day + "']")).click();
        System.out.println("Element is clicked.");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
```

For my `String day` parameter, it shows me this error: Parameter count mismatch(found 1 expected 0) with step annotation : 'pick two days after current day'

Basically, i am trying to pick a date for a flight from datepicker. I have to pick two days after the current day of month but i got a little bit confused.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote another method and works like a charm now:

```
@Step("read text value of the element with <id>")
    public void readTextValue(String id) throws InterruptedException {
        String currentDate = appiumDriver.findElement(By.id(id)).getText();
        System.out.println("Element has been read.");
        int dayToPick = Integer.parseInt(currentDate) + 2;
        String dayToPickAsText = String.valueOf(dayToPick);
        appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='" + dayToPickAsText + "']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
```